# Django form not submitting upon click

Tags: html, django, forms, http-post

I don't know why my code is not submitting. I search on the internet and cannot find any solution.

```
 {% extends 'root/base.html' %}
    {% block title %}{{title}}{% endblock %}

    {% block body %}
    <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form method="post" action="{% url 'shopapp:signup' %}">
                {% csrf_token %} 
                {% for field in form %}
                    {{field.label}}
                    <p>{{field}}</p>
                {% endfor %}
                <p><input type="submit"  value="Signup" class="btn btn-danger"></p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div> 
 </div>
 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The form is not showing any error just that when I hit the submit button nothing happens,  no data is send over the server